# A bug or not a bug (get_paginate_by)

Tags: django

This is a code from Django itself.

Please, pay attention that queryset is not used in the method.

Well, I can't even imagine how it can be used here.

Could you tell me whether this is a bug or not? If it is, I could raise a ticket at Djangoproject.

If this is not a bug, we should clarify the purpose of this parameter in the comment. In this case I also could raise a ticket.

Or everything is ok here?

**django/views/generic/list.py**

```
class MultipleObjectMixin(ContextMixin):

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        """
        Get the number of items to paginate by, or ``None`` for no pagination.
        """
        return self.paginate_by
```

Comment: That’s just the interface definition of the method - you *can* use the queryset, but aren’t *required* to. Per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/): *“By default this simply returns the value of paginate_by”*.

Comment: Well, why is it here? If it is necessary here, let it be. But I'd rather have the purpose clarified. If it is useless, it should be removed from the interface, isn't it?

Comment: This conversation really belongs to the Django bugtracker, not here.

Comment: @Michael what do you mean *”here”*? *”If it is useless”* - to whom? Just because the default implementation doesn’t use the parameter does **not** mean it should be removed, that would make no sense at all. And what clarification to its usage would you like - it’s there to give you access to the queryset being paginated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine if you want to extend MultipleObjectMixin, you would want your default implementation to have methods that you can override and will keep you out of copy-pasting base method core code.

If you think about it there is not much sense to have a method that returns already set value if thought is not on extending it.

In this case, creator of Mixin thought that you could need queryset in some of the use cases of extending following function.